# Laravel Redirect to Previous after login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a login form and after the form submission (if validation is OK) the browser should redirect to the **last page before login**. Currently I redirect back and I get always into the same login page.
My routes.php is something like this:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/list','EventController@index');
Route::get('/login','AuthController@login');
Route::post('/login','AuthController@do_login');
```

And my Redirection inside do_login() is

```
if(Login_is_valid())
{
    return Redirect::back();
}
```

If I'm inside /list page and then open Login and fill the form correctly I'm redirected to /login again isn't it weird? Many thanks

Comment: The response is perfectly valid. After submitting a form from a page, the `back()` would in fact redirect you to the same page. Do a `return redirect('url goes here')`

Comment: Damn, so whenever I enter login page I have to store in $_SESSION the referer ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect to the intended route?

Comment: yes, for instance I'm inside /list so I have to be redirected to there. It can be done with sessions, but I don't know if it is the "prettiest" solution

Comment: Try `return Redirect::intended();`

Comment: return Redirect::intended(); redirects me to the homepage

Comment: You use Laravel 5 or Laravel 5.1 ?

Comment: Laravel Framework version 5.0.33

Answer (score 8):

Hello if you use Laravel 5.1 you can redirect to previous page next way

```
return back();
```

or you can use Session where Laravel save previous page

```
return redirect(Session::get('_previous')['url']);
```

Answer (score 0):

in **Auth/LoginController** there is **`protected $redirectTo = '/home';`** change **'/home'** to **'/loginin'** for example, and create a new route that look like this

```
Route::get('/loginin', function ()
{
        $page = '/' . session()->get('page');
        if($page != '')
        {
            session()->put('page', '');
            return redirect($page);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/home');
        }
});
```

or you can put this in an controller and call it from the route

and in each function in the pages controller this code

```
session->put('page','/name_of_the_page');
```